# Can't open keycharmap file in android

Tags: android

4.0 version is perfectly working but if i have to running 2.2 nothing to happen . i didn't get any data from web service 
.I have mention below log cat message :

```
03-29 11:22:34.671: W/KeyCharacterMap(18884): Can't open keycharmap file
03-29 11:22:34.671: W/KeyCharacterMap(18884): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/sec_touchscreen_.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='sec_touchscreen '
03-29 11:22:34.671: W/KeyCharacterMap(18884): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-29 11:29:57.765: W/KeyCharacterMap(19340): Can't open keycharmap file
03-29 11:29:57.765: W/KeyCharacterMap(19340): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/sec_touchscreen_.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='sec_touchscreen '
03-29 11:29:57.765: W/KeyCharacterMap(19340): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-29 11:33:34.218: W/ActivityThread(19627): Application com.doodleblue.dinein is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-29 11:33:34.226: I/System.out(19627): Sending WAIT chunk
03-29 11:33:34.429: I/System.out(19627): Debugger has connected
```

Please give me any solution for me?

Comment: R u running in emulator or in real Device. If it is emulator you have to choose Google api at the time of creating AVD